# Visual Studio does not display remote message from Git on a reject of push

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a pre-receive hook in place in my remote repo that check commit messages and rejects pushes if information is missing.

The pre-receive hook returns messages for why the commit is rejected so the others can amend the message accordingly and push again.

This is working just fine with Git Bash and Git GUI but Visual Studio Source Control output for Git simply does not display the remote messages.

Is it possible to change the behaviour of Visual Studio so it display the messages returned from remote?

Comment: did you check in the OUTPUT window of visual studio ?

Comment: This is all I have: `The following errors were reported during push:
 refs/heads/master, pre-receive hook declined`

Comment: I guess the workaround is to 'Open Command Prompt' to run push again. Not ideal but it does the job.